# I can't delete on row of data in Wakanda

Tags: wakanda

In Wakanda Studio Enterprise, I can't delete one row of data, I have a network error

- 401 (Unauthorized) 
  or 500 (Internal Server Error)

I enabled `CORS` and allow all and all request methods.

I would like to know if someone can delete on row of data in their 4D Server.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide a sample of your code or additional information to help us? These kinds of errors can be because of missing authentication. Delete operations are usually available after it.